# Solve polynomial system

Tags: equation-solving, polynomials

I am trying to solve

```
Solve[t23*(n12 - x123 - x124 + x1234)*(n13 - x123 - x134 + 
x1234) == (x123 - x1234)*(n1 - n12 - n13 - n14 + x134 + x123 + 
x124 - x1234) && 
t24*(n12 - x123 - x124 + x1234)*(n14 - x124 - x134 + 
x1234) == (x124 - x1234)*(n1 - n12 - n13 - n14 + x134 + x123 + 
x124 - x1234) && 
t34*(n13 - x123 - x134 + x1234)*(n14 - x124 - x134 + 
x1234) == (x134 - x1234)*(n1 - n12 - n13 - n14 + x134 + x123 + 
x124 - x1234) && 
t234*(n1 - n12 - n13 - n14 + x134 + x123 + x124 - x1234)*(x134 - 
x1234)*(x124 - x1234)*(x123 - x1234) == (n12 - x123 - x124 + 
x1234)*(n13 - x123 - x134 + x1234)*(n14 - x124 - x134 + 
x1234), {x123, x124, x134, x1234}]
```

where all 4 variables should be reals `0<=x<=1`, all the `n` parameters are also `0<=n<=1`, and `t` parameters are `0<=t<Infinity`. It says running but no output is returned :-(

Comment: It is most likely bogged in computational complexity since it is dealing with parameters. If it helps, might instead use `NSolve` when parameters are given actual values.

Comment: I assume you have tried `Reduce` and similar commands instead? My real question is where did these equations come from? How did they arise? (There's really no guarantee that arbitrary systems of polynomials can be solved, reduced, simplified in a helpful way.)

Comment: After several hours of processing, my 16GB computer ran out of memory.  Perhaps, this is your situation as well.